# remove first occurence if two are present in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a file with some text in the following format:

> this is random text ("why" "because" "who"; "why" "who") again some random text

So all the words to select are beetween parentethis and each word is inside quotes.

So I need some bash code to remove the first occurence of any word that is already in the second part (after the semi-colon).
In the exemple above, the result of the command would be:

> this is random text ("because"; "why" "who") again some random text

thanks

Comment: What have you tried to do? Why does the first occurrence of "random text" not get removed? Is it only words in quotes? Only words inside the parentheses? You need an array of all the words you want to remove, then loop over them. Show effort and people will help you.

Comment: I'll try to stock the 9 words in an array and to loop over them, I'll let you know how it goes... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it could be done:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{split($2,a,";");n=split(a[2],b," ");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) gsub(b[i],x,a[1]);print $1 "(" a[1] ";" a[2] ")" $3}' file
this is random text ( "because" ; "why" "who") again some random text
```

---

Or written like this

```
awk -F"[()]" '
    {split($2,a,";")
    n=split(a[2],b," ")
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        gsub(b[i],x,a[1])
    print $1 "(" a[1] ";" a[2] ")" $3}
    ' file
```

Comment: Nice, but I wonder what happens if one of the `b[i]` contains regex characters?

Comment: @HåkonHægland nasal demons... :-). Never do this.

Comment: @HåkonHægland The example does not have it. In programming there is nearly impossible to make a 100% fail free solution.  Do you know what distribution that comes with gawk 4.xx installed?  Ubuntu is still on 3.xx

Comment: @Jotne No I do not know if Ubuntu has upgraded to gawk version 4. You can install it manually, though, as I suggested in a previous comment

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu Awk version 4 you could use

```
gawk -f a.awk file
```

where `a.awk` is

```
{
    n=patsplit($0,L,"\\(.*\\)",S)
    split(L[1],a,";")
    n1=patsplit(a[1],b,"\"[^\"]*\"",s1)
    n2=patsplit(a[2],c,"\"[^\"]*\"",s2)
    for (i=1; i<=n1; i++)
        for (j=1; j<=n2; j++)
            if (b[i]==c[j])
                b[i]=""
    printf "%s%s",S[0],s1[0]
    for (i=1;i<=n1; i++)
        printf "%s%s",b[i],s1[i]
    printf ";%s%s\n",a[2],S[1]
}
```

with output

```
this is random text ( "because" ; "why" "who") again some random text
```

Comment: patsplit(), etc. take an RE argument. By using string delimiters (`"..."`) instead of RE delimiters (`/.../`) arounf the RE you're telling awk that the RE is inside a string instead of a hard-coded RE and so awk parses the string twice, once when the script is read and then again when it is executed and so you are forced to escape RE metacharacters twice. If you simly use RE delimiters instead of string delimiters then you save yourself that headache. In this case, it'd be `patsplit($0,L,/\(.*\)/,S)` for example. This also removes the need to escape `"`s, e.g. `patsplit(a[1],b,/"[^"]*"/,s1)`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes I fully agree with this. Thanks for the comment. I do not know why I did this..

Answer (score 1):

I'd start something like this with awk, untested:

```
match($0,/[(][^)]+/) {
     head = substr($0,1,RSTART)
     body = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
     tail = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)

     split(body,parts,/;/)

     ....
     do stuff with parts to rebuild body
     ....

     print head body tail
}
```